# Как изменить цвет текста элемента listbox

Tags: c#, listbox

Используется winforms

Есть `listbox1` заполненный из базы 1, затем берется элемент из другой базы 2, и нужно найти элемент в `listbox1` и если он есть изменить его цвет.

например:

- база 1 содержит id (`long`) пользователей -нужный цвет в `listbox1`(без цвета)
- база 2 содержит бан id (`long`) -нужный цвет в `listbox1`(красный)
- база 3 содержит id (`long`) сотрудников -нужный цвет в `listbox1`(жёлтый)

с начало выводятся в `listbox` все id затем раскрашиваются или раскрашиваются в момент вывода

вывод в listbox сейчас

```
BeginInvoke(new Action(() => listBox4.Items.Add("id"+idPip[i1])));
```

Comment: Укажите используемую технологию построения интерфейса. Чем является элемент, цвет которого нужно изменить? Item в listbox1?

Comment: добавил .......

Comment: Добавьте используемую технологию. Если я правильно помню в WinForms подобные раскрашивания невозможны.

Comment: что вы подразумеваете под словом технология? я новичок, я вас не понимаю

Comment: winforms, wpf, uwp, qt и тд. То, что вы используете для создания пользовательского интерфейса

Comment: А изменения фона под текстом элемента ? есть поле backColor, но как им пользоваться ?

Comment: используется winforms

Comment: backColor - это фон всего элемента. Вы не можете подсветить отдельные id использую стандартный элемент listbox. Но вы можете сделать это используя DataGridView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробую перевести [англоязычный ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91747/background-color-of-a-listbox-item-winforms)

Один из способов сделать то, что вы хотите, это установить `DrawMode` как `OwnerDrawFixed`. После этого вы можете подписаться на событие `DrawItem` и вручную нарисовать каждый нужный вам элемент.

Пример кода:

```
class MyForm : Form
{
    public MyForm()
    {
        var lb = new ListBox();
        var data = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).ToArray();
        lb.DataSource = data;

        lb.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;

        lb.DrawItem += (sender, e) => {
            e.DrawBackground();
            Graphics g = e.Graphics;

            var val = (int)lb.Items[e.Index];

            g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(val %2 == 0 ? Color.Silver : Color.LightGreen), e.Bounds);
            g.DrawString(val.ToString(), e.Font, new SolidBrush(e.ForeColor), e.Bounds);

            e.DrawFocusRectangle();
        };

        this.Controls.Add(lb);      
    }
}
```

Результат

[image: Результат]